# Is there any point in scanning video files with MS Defender?

Tags: video, anti-virus, windows-defender

I have a policy of always scanning any newly-aquired files with MS Defender before I open them.

But I've noticed that if I scan a video file then no matter how large the file, MS Defender will near-instantaneously declare it a non-threat. Whereas scanning other types of files - even ones significantly smaller - can see MS Defender take a noticeable amount of time before delivering its verdict.

This has caused me to suspect that all that happens with video files is that first the extension is checked, then once MS Defender sees that it is a known video filetype, it immediately decides that it isn't a threat and stops scanning.

Is this suspicion correct? If it is, then I can stop needlessly scanning video files.

As a bonus, IF I am correct and MS Defender judges video files as non-threats because of their extensions, is this true of other media files such as audio and image files? Again, there is of course no point spending time scanning files that will automatically be deemed to be non-threats.

Comment: so, as a rule, malware needs to be executable code. content formats usually do not qualify, because the binary of the file is not in the form of a executable so it can't actually do anything on its own. it is possible that a program that loads content files might have vulnerabilities in its parser, or misuse the content runtime, that a boobytrapped file might exploit to make the program misbehave, but that is uncommon in image/video files. its pretty common with word or PDF files though.

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but years ago my antivirus has caught an infected video file - not sure if it was the video itself or some loader (as mentioned by the above comment), but the whole file was quarantined... So I'd say it isn't a waste of time to scan these files...

Comment: I know it is theoretically possible for a video to be infected. However, if MS Defender automatically decides that files with a known video file extension are safe, then it will not detect any such threats. Hence it would be pointless scanning them with it. And so this query about how MS Defender handles video files.